# R Markdown file slow to knit due to large dataset

Tags: r, caching, r-markdown, knitr

I am new to R Markdown. Apologies if the question has an obvious answer that I missed.

Context:

I am working with a large dataset in R Markdown (roughly 90 million rows) to produce a short report. While working on the file formatting, I want to knit the final HTML document frequently (e.g., after making a change) to look at the formatting.

Problem:

The problem is the dataset takes a long time to be load and so the each knit takes a long time to be executed (roughly five to ten minutes). I do need all of the data, so loading in a smaller file isn't a workable option. Of course, I am able to code the individual chunks since the data are loaded into the global environment, but formatting is in credibly onerous since it is difficult to visualize the result of formatting changes without looking at the knitted product.

Attempts to solve the issue:

After some research, I found and tried to use `cache = TRUE` and `cache.extra = file.mtime('my-precious.csv')` [(as per this section of Yihui's Bookdown)](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache.html). However, this option didn't work as it resulted in the following:

```
Error in lazyLoadDBinsertVariable(vars[i], from, datafile, ascii, compress,  : 
  long vectors not supported yet: connections.c:6073
Calls: <Anonymous> ... <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> lazyLoadDBinsertVariable
```

To overcome this error, I added `cache.lazy = FALSE` into the chunk options ([as mentioned here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/cache-lazy.html)). Unfortunately, while the code worked, the time it took to knit the document did not go down.

My limited understanding of this process is that having `cache = TRUE` and `cache.extra = file.mtime('my-precious.csv')` will lead to a code chunk's executed results be cached so that the next time the file is knit, results from the previous run are loaded. However, because my file is too large, `cache = TRUE` doesn't work so I have to use `cache.lazy = FALSE` to turn reverse what is done by `cache = TRUE`. In the end, this means that the dataset is being loaded into my memory each time I run the file, thereby lengthening the time it take to knit the document.

Questions to which I seek answers from the R community:

1. Is there a way to cache the data-loading chunk in R Markdown when the file size is large (~90 million rows)?
2. Is there a (better) way to circumvent the time-intensive data-loading process every time I knit the R Markdown file?
3. Is my understanding of the `cache = TRUE` method of circumventing the time-intensive data-loading process correct? And if it isn't, why didn't the `cache = TRUE` method work for me?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 90 million rows will take time to load, no matter what the issue. No, there's no easy way to have it inexpensively just "available" in the knitted document: starting these documents from an austere/empty environment is key for reproducibility and a good thing, so I think trying to defy that is not the best path. Also, while you are trying to use knitr's `cache=`, in reality you're still going to load-time problems. What format is the data file? How are you loading it? I suggest you work on reducing that step.

Comment: Depending on your data, another thing you may want to do (for iteratively development/editing) is to load just a subset of the data for just a component of your report. I know you say you need it all, but perhaps you can sample the data and work on the aesthetics of your tables/plots even if the actual results contained within them is incomplete.

Comment: `cache=TRUE` helps when the original data goes through multiple intensive and time consuming transformations after the initial loading process, by caching intermediate objects. But it does not free us from loading the raw/initial data.

Comment: The OP did not specifically mention the method used for loading the data, but I strongly suggest you make sure a fast method is being used. `data.table::fread()` can be significantly faster (up to a >10-fold decrease in loading time) than `base::read.csv`

Comment: @r2evans and @GuedesBF, thank you for comments. @r2evans - That's right, creating a subset (of, say, 10,000 rows) should work. Statistically, it should capture the characteristics of the dataset. I would then only need to run the final data once.
@GuedesBF - I am currently loading RData/RDS files. The original data came in txt files, I then use ```read.fwf``` to save the data as RData files. I've found the RData/RDS format to take a few minutes to load into R, which is exponentially faster.

Is ```fread()``` faster than ```load``` and ```read_rds```?

Answer (score 3):

*Is there a (better) way to circumvent the time-intensive data-loading process every time I knit the R Markdown file?*

Yes. Perform your computations **outside** of the Rmarkdown report.

Plots can be saved into files and included into the report via `knitr::include_graphics(myfile)`
Tables can be saved into smaller summary files, loaded via `fread` and displayed via `kable`.

Note that if you need to print tables in a loop, you should specify the `result=asis` chunk option.

````
```{r my_chunk_label, results='asis', echo=F}
for(i in 1:length(data_full)) {
  print(kable(data_full[[i]]))
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

Run your expensive computations once, save the results. Consume these results with a light `Rmarkdown` report that is easy to format.

If you still have large csv files to load, you should use `data.table::fread` which is much more efficient than base functions.

I actually posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73299267/faster-way-to-ggplot-ggarrange) not so long ago. You're not alone.

Comment: Thanks, guat. This is a workable suggestion, although then the reproducibility of the final product is then predicated on several an R script and an R Markdown file. While this isn't a downside inherently, it is a personal preference to keep all the code in one side. Thanks for the fread() suggestion as well.